# PostgreSQL regexp_matches only returning rows that match it?

Tags: postgresql

This is my first time using regexp_matches and I find that using it will only return rows that match all regexp_matches in the SELECT clause.

For example:

```
SELECT parameters, 
regexp_matches(parameters, 'a=(\d+)'), 
regexp_matches(parameters, 'b=(\d+)')
FROM table;
```

Will return result with row where parameters is `a=1&b=1` but not `a=1` or `b=1`

It's acting as if it was a where clause. Why is this?

Answer (score 5):

This is because `regexp_matches()` returns set of rows. 
With no matches it returns no rows.

Use search by one regexp, e.g.:

```
SELECT 
    parameters, 
    regexp_matches(parameters, '[a|b]=(\d+)')
FROM a_table;
```

or, if you want to get two columns for `a`and `b`:

```
SELECT parameters, a, b
FROM (
    SELECT 
        parameters, 
        regexp_matches(parameters, 'a=(\d+)') a,
        null b
    FROM a_table
    UNION
    SELECT 
        parameters,
        null,
        regexp_matches(parameters, 'b=(\d+)')
    FROM a_table
    ) s;
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way around this is to match on the end of the string in addition to the pattern you want to find.

```
SELECT parameters,
regexp_matches(parameters, '(a=(\d+))|$'), 
regexp_matches(parameters, '(b=(\d+))|$')
FROM table;
```

Then you might want to do some other processing since any string missing the pattern will show up in results as `{NULL}` (or `{NULL,NULL<,...>}`, one per match group).

Answer (score 0):

the `regexp_matches` function returns set of rows. If no rows are returned, the row gets filtered.

To work around this, you can try the following

```sql
SELECT parameters, 
  array(select * from regexp_matches(parameters, 'a=(\d+)')), 
  array(select * from regexp_matches(parameters, 'b=(\d+)'))
FROM table;
```