# function regexp_matches can limit number of resulting rows when used in select column

Tags: postgresql

Already 8 years ago, it was discovered that function `regexp_matches` can limit the number of returned rows when used as a column in a select: [PostgreSQL regexp_matches only returning rows that match it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34210618/postgresql-regexp-matches-only-returning-rows-that-match-it)

To me this seems to be a severe defect, but it seems that the postgres community does not care?

a) What line of thinking am I missing that makes this acceptable?

b) Are there any other examples where the columns in a select can reduce the number of resulting rows?

**Providing an example:**

```
-- 1 row
select 1;

-- 1 row
select 1,now();

--1 row
select 1,regexp_matches('lala','la');

-- Suddenly no row
select 1,regexp_matches('lala','hi');
```

In my thinking the expressions that I provide in the [select list](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#:%7E:text=Section%C2%A07.2.5.-,SELECT%20List,-The%20SELECT%20list) should not be allowed to have outside effects like altering the number of rows returned. Their effects with regards to what the query returns should be limited to what is returned in that field/column. `select * from ...` provides the same amount of result rows as `select 1 from ...`, why is `select regexp_matches(...) from ...` exempt from this rule? Is there really no rule for that? Shouldn't the expected behaviour for `select 1,regexp_matches('lala','hi');` be that one row is returned with values 1, NULL?

Comment: No one cares because it is working as designed.  Other examples?  Sure, any set-returning function which is capable of returning zero rows. (It is best to put set-returning functions in the FROM, not the SELECT.  Then you can use LEFT joins if you want to)

Comment: regexp_matches() doesn't return rows at all, it returns a text array. And that array can be NULL as well. Why do you think it's a defect? Do you have an example?

Comment: @FrankHeikens I have added an example.

Comment: @Peter I agree this can be a surprise, but it's not a defect or bug. It's even documented in the manual: `Without the sub-select, this query would produce no output at all for table rows without a match, which is typically not the desired behavior.` See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-POSIX-REGEXP

Comment: ty for your input and the interesting link. in my world view this still is a defect, when the behavior of something goes so against the expectation of the majority of users. but my world view does not matter. also, I would have expected to find such a fundamental concept (that the columns of the select list can reduce the number of resulting rows) at least in the documentation of the 'select list': https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#:~:text=Section%C2%A07.2.5.-,SELECT%20List,-The%20SELECT%20list